# Bootstrap 3 Showing Wrong Breakpoints

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, breakpoints, bootstrap-sass

I installed Twitter Bootstrap 3 using the bootstrap-sass gem, like I do on all my projects. However, on this project the breakpoints are being called incorrectly. I can't tell exactly what resolution it's rendering for my screen, but it's wrong. I had to custom set my breakpoints to smaller values in order to get it to work. I'm using the standard structure as follows:

**In my application.html.haml**

```
!!!
/ paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/
/[if lt IE 7 ] <html class="ie6" lang="en">
/[if IE 7 ] <html class="ie7" lang="en">
/[if IE 8 ] <html class="ie8" lang="en">
/ [if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!

%html{:lang => "en"}
  / <![endif]

  %head
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
    / Uncomment to make IE8 render like IE7
    / <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
    / Set the viewport width to device width for mobile
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}/
    %title= full_title(yield(:title))
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300|Grand+Hotel'
    = csrf_meta_tags


  / |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||


  %body
    .navigation
      = render 'layouts/nav'
    .wrapper
      .flash
        - flash.each do |key, value|
          %div{:class => "alert-box alert-#{key}"}= value
      = yield
      = javascript_include_tag "application"
    .footer
      / = render 'layouts/footer'
      = debug(params) if Rails.env.development?
```

I then call on the bootstrap classes on each specific page (because I want to use full backgrounds and text that is offset) as follows:

**home.html.haml**

```
#textbox
    .row
        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-10.col-lg-10.col-md-offset-1.col-lg-offset-1
             content goes here
```

You can convert my haml to erb using this tool: http://www.haml-converter.com/. Aside from that, I really don't know what could be doing it. Perhaps it's because I call on bootstrap using @import "bootstrap"; in application.css.scss? I tried doing it using *= require but I was warned against doing so on the git repo. Additionally, when I did so, google fonts were not being loaded. Finally, it might be helpful to mention that when I originally created the project, I had issues with bootstrap where the .row was flowing over the maximum width of the window by about 15px on each side. I fixed this by setting margins on right and left of .row to 0.

Thank you for your help in advance, and all the best to you!

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses an awesome GRID SYSTEM which forms the backbone of an application. If you are using bootstrap then its a MUST READ !! refer these

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/

[Bootstrap 3.0 Grid Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075279/bootstrap-3-0-grid-explanation)

Please remove the unwanted `/` in front of each lines. I think you converted initial erb code to haml using an online converter and that's why all those popped up.

In HAML indentation is everything. You can go through the docs here

http://haml.info/docs.html

Make sure you clean the poorly indented code first and someone will surely help you out.

Comment: The / in front of some of the lines is for commenting.